# How to stop all stack operations currently running in cloud formation?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, server, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

Probably everyone that has worked before with CloudFormation knows **how annoying it is when you run a provision or an update** for one of your CloudFormation stacks **and you realise you made a mistake**. You then have to **wait hours or days before all the operations rollback or fail**.

AWS Documentation it's a maze so it's basically impossible to get an answer there and after days researching I came to the conclusion to try here to debunk a myth: **How to stop all stack operations currently running in cloud formation?**

I managed to understand how, *for the update*, using the `awscli` option `cancel-update-stack`, even if it doesn't work all then time. At that point you **probably** need to delete your stack using the option `delete-stack` (**!NB: this option will erase all the infrastructure for the stack you called it for**)

Although when I run a creation I can't manage to interrupt it, I always have to wait for all the operations to rollback or fail.

If you guys know anything that could enrich this explanation please share it!

Answer (score 1):

> when I run a creation I can't manage to interrupt it, I always have to wait for all the operations to rollback or fail.

No way around this as far as I know. If `cancel-update-stack` doesn't work, you need to wait. Working with CloudFormation requires a fair bit of patience but can yield great results once you get it right.

Check out the `cfn-lint` tool, might help you avoid some of the errors that are avoidable but can take a while to manifest during an update: https://github.com/martysweet/cfn-lint

Comment: Thanks @arco444, I just installed the library. Definitely a good add-on for avoiding basic errors. Although I just ran it using my template and parameters and no errors where found but still the stack fails. I really appreciate the advise though, patience is the key!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this today as I was trying to stop CloudFormation from creating a new stack that was never going to work. I was able to go to the console and delete the stack. This actually succeeded in my case.